# Error while compiling protobuf-net generated codecode

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Have funny error in protobuf-net generated code. .proto definition file contains field named "value" for an object. What protogen.exe generated for that value with -p:detectMissing option:

```
    private int? _value;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(50, IsRequired = false, Name=@"value", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
    [global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(@"value", Order = 50)]

    public int value
    {
        get { return _value ?? default(int); }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    [global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
    public bool valueSpecified
    {
      get { return _value != null; }
        set { if (value == (_value == null)) _value = value ? value : (int?)null; }
    }
    private bool ShouldSerializevalue() { return valueSpecified; }
    private void Resetvalue() { valueSpecified = false; }
```

Compiler produces an error thinking that **value** is a keyword but not class property:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'bool' and 'int?'

Made workaround manually altering generated code:

```
public int valueWorkaround
{
    get { return _value ?? default(int); }
}

public bool valueSpecified
{
  get { return _value != null; }
    set { if (value == (_value == null)) _value = value ? valueWorkaround : (int?)null; }
}
```

However probably it makes sense to fix code generation also?

Comment: Hmmm... there is keyword-checking code in there (for adding @ etc) - guess I missed one. I'll take a look.

Comment: @marc I'm facing the same issue on two different computers (with same version of VS and ProtoBufGenerator) ... On one computer the `this` is added correctly while on other computer it is not ... extremely strange ... Can't really tell for ProtoBufGenerator version as dll indicate 1.0.0.0 (Installer we used for both computers was `protobuf-net-VS10.msi`).

Comment: @CitizenInsane in the install folder you should be able to compare the files directly; for codegen, the most important things are the xslt, however: the version from protobuf-net.dll will help understand exactly what point in time (svn commit) they were built from

Comment: @marc Thank you Marc, indeed if starting from same installer, someone manually edited the `csharp.xslt` file and prefixed `XXX` with `this.XXX` when generating code for `public bool XXXSpecified` to workaround fields called `value` ... he just forgot to warn everyone in the team for this modification.

Comment: @marc @aleksey For information, I have placed modified `csharp.xslt` here: https://gist.github.com/3748744 ... Only few lines have been modified compared to the one installed with `protobuf-net-VS10.msi` and intend only to workaround fields named `value`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense to fix the code generation. I guess, you should report it to the project contributors.